# How to switch to code mode in Android Studio Giraffe with New UI?

Tags: android-studio

Before I can switch like this:
[image: Android Studio Flamingo]

But now I install Android Studio Giraffe with New UI icon set and don't see these buttons.
[image]

I can switch with hotkeys, but I want to see buttons.

А few days later I saw the icon at the top of the panel (was not there before)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here it is! I've also struggled a little bit to find it:

[image]